# Texture/Shading problem

Tags: texturing, materials, uv-image-editor

I'm having the following problem;
Part is textured on a solid red using a basic image file, but as you see some parts show strange shading. Normals are ok and all faces turned out.
Any advice?

[image: Bad shading]

[image: Bad shading close]

Comment: Can you attach your Blender .blend file with the problem mesh?  The simplest file which demonstrates the problem is desirable.  Small size file is  desirable.

Comment: It looks like normals issue alright, without a blend file it will be hard to diagnose.